# how to drop similar values in pandas using levenshtein function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which looks like -

```
   ML_ENTITY_NAME        EDT_ENTITY_NAME
1  ABC BANK              HABIB METROPOLITAN BANK
2  ABC BANK              HABIB METROPOLITIAN BANK
3  BANK OF AMERICA       HSBC BANK MALAYSIA BHD
4  BANK OF AMERICA       HSBC BANK MALAYSIA SDN BHD
5  BANK OF NEW ZEALAND   HUA NAN COMMERCIAL BANK
6  BANK OF NEW ZEALAND   HUA NAN COMMERCIAL BANK LTD
7  CITIBANK N.A.         CHINA GUANGFA BANK CO LTD
8  CITIBANK N.A.         CHINA GUANGFA BANK CO.,LTD
9  SECURITY BANK CORP.   SECURITY BANK CORP
10 SIAM COMMERCIAL BANK  THE SIAM COMMERCIAL BANK PCL
11 TEMU                  ANZ BANK SAMOA LTD
```

I have written a levenshtein function which loooks like -

```
def fm(s1, s2):
    score = Levenshtein.distance(s1,s2)
    if score == 0.0:
        score = 1.0
    else:
        score = 1 - (score / len(s1))
    return score
```

I wanted to write a code that if the levenstein score of two `EDT_ENTITY_NAME` values is `greater than .75` then we drop the one value having less length and retain the one having more length.Also the `ML_ENTITY_NAME` for comparison should be same.

My final output should looks like -

```
   ML_ENTITY_NAME        EDT_ENTITY_NAME
1  ABC BANK              HABIB METROPOLITIAN BANK
2  BANK OF AMERICA       HSBC BANK MALAYSIA SDN BHD
3  BANK OF NEW ZEALAND   HUA NAN COMMERCIAL BANK LTD
4  CITIBANK N.A.         CHINA GUANGFA BANK CO.,LTD
5  SECURITY BANK CORP.   SECURITY BANK CORP
6  SIAM COMMERCIAL BANK  THE SIAM COMMERCIAL BANK PCL
7  TEMU                  ANZ BANK SAMOA LTD
```

Currently my approach is to sort the df and iterate over the loop and check if ML_ENTITY_NAME values are same then calculate the levenshtein for EDT_ENTITY_NAME. i have added a new column delete and I'm updating the delete column to 1 if the above conditions satifies and the length one ML_ENTITY_NAME is smaller than other ML_ENTITY_NAME.

my code looks like -

```
df.sort_values(by=['ML_ENTITY_NAME','EDT_ENTITY_NAME'],inplace=True)
df['delete']=0
for row1 in df.itertuples():
    for row2 in df.itertuples():
        if (str(row1.ML_ENTITY_NAME) == str(row2.ML_ENTITY_NAME)) and (1>fm(str(row1.EDT_ENTITY_NAME),str(row2.EDT_ENTITY_NAME))>.74):

            if(len(row1.EDT_ENTITY_NAME)>len(row2.EDT_ENTITY_NAME)):
                df.loc[row2.Index,row2[2]]=1
print(df)
```

currently it's giving wrong output.

can someone help me with some answers/hints/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
#cross join by ML_ENTITY_NAME column
df1 = df.merge(df, on='ML_ENTITY_NAME', how='outer')
#remove same values per rows (distance 1)
df1 = df1[df1['EDT_ENTITY_NAME_x'] != df1['EDT_ENTITY_NAME_y']]
#apply function and compare
m1 = df1.apply(lambda x: fm(x['EDT_ENTITY_NAME_x'], x['EDT_ENTITY_NAME_y']), axis=1) > .75
m2 = df1['EDT_ENTITY_NAME_x'].str.len() > df1['EDT_ENTITY_NAME_y'].str.len()

#filtering
df2 = df1.loc[m1 & m2, ['ML_ENTITY_NAME','EDT_ENTITY_NAME_x']]
#remove  `_x`
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.replace('_x$', '')
#add unique rows per ML_ENTITY_NAME
df2 = df2.append(df[~df['ML_ENTITY_NAME'].duplicated(keep=False)]).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df2)
         ML_ENTITY_NAME               EDT_ENTITY_NAME
0              ABC BANK      HABIB METROPOLITIAN BANK
1       BANK OF AMERICA    HSBC BANK MALAYSIA SDN BHD
2   BANK OF NEW ZEALAND   HUA NAN COMMERCIAL BANK LTD
3         CITIBANK N.A.    CHINA GUANGFA BANK CO.,LTD
4   SECURITY BANK CORP.            SECURITY BANK CORP
5  SIAM COMMERCIAL BANK  THE SIAM COMMERCIAL BANK PCL
6                  TEMU            ANZ BANK SAMOA LTD
```

Comment: here you are getting the score between ML_ENTITY_NAME  and EDT_ENTITY_NAME .

Comment: @MadhurYadav - please check now.

Answer (score 1):

Could you specify what exactly is wrong about the output you are getting? The only deviation from your goal I see in code is that you only set the `delete` flag to 1 for row pairs with **0.74 < fm(...) < 1**, while it should be rather **0.75 < fm(...)**.

As a side note, sorting is redundant in your code, since you end up comparing every possible pair of rows anyways. What you possibly had in mind when implementing the sorting was going through each *consecutive* pair of rows, which would improve the complexity of your code from O(n<sup>2</sup>) to O(n).

Another side note is that you don't need the `if` statement in your `fm` function:  statement `score = 1 - score / len(s1)` would cover both cases.

Comment: 1. earilier my idea for sorting was to also compare the first letters of the values and run the loop if they are same. hence I'll be saving execution time. since the variations in my file are mostly in the end, eg = bank of america , bank of america co., bank of america co. ltd. 

2. my output is wrong because the delete columns are not getting updated, and several columns of EDT_ENTITY_NAME values are coming in columns. I guess my O(n^2) loop on the same df is not working properly.

Comment: It seems to me you pass the 2nd index to `df.loc` incorrectly. `row2[2]` will always be the value of `delete` column, initialized as 0, and thus never to be changed. Consider using `'delete'` instead: `df.loc[row2.Index, 'delete'] = 1`

Comment: I tried it but i was showing error - **TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str**